# Как вызвать метод клаcа(java)

Tags: java

```
public class lab2 {
    int[][] C;
    byte sum = 0;
    int min;
    class test {
        public void Matrix(byte[][] mas1, byte[][] mas2) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= mas1.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= mas1[i].length - 1; j++) {
                    C[i][j] = mas1[i][j] + mas2[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= C[0].length; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
                    min = C[i][0];
                    if (min > C[i][j]) {
                        min = C[i][j];
                    }
                }
                sum += min;
            }
        }
    }


       byte mas1[][] = {{5, 7, 1}, {1, 55, 8}, {33, 2, 54}};
       byte mas2[][] = {{45, 49, 21}, {75, 5, 0}};
       lab2 s = new lab2();
       s.Matrix(mas1, mas2);
   }
```

Только начал изучать джаву. Последняя строчка выдает ошибку. Где ошибка и как правильно реализовать код? Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Ну видимо стоит открыть книжку и перечитать про вложенные классы. Заодно прочитать текст ошибки, там наверняка что-нибудь полезное.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы вызвать метод вложенного класса, в первую очередь нужно создать экземпляр вложенного класса:

```
test s = new lab2().new test();
```

А после этого вызывать `s.Matrix(args)`.

В конце концов, в вашем коде нету метода `main` и я не очень понимаю, что именно вы запускаете здесь? 
Вот так вы сможете попасть в желаемый метод:

```
public class lab2 {
int[][] C = new int[1000][1000];
byte sum = 0;
int min;
class test {
    public void Matrix(byte[][] mas1, byte[][] mas2) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= mas1.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= mas1[i].length - 1; j++) {
                C[i][j] = mas1[i][j] + mas2[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= C[0].length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
                min = C[i][0];
                if (min > C[i][j]) {
                    min = C[i][j];
                }
            }
            sum += min;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   byte mas1[][] = {{5, 7, 1}, {1, 55, 8}, {33, 2, 54}};
   byte mas2[][] = {{45, 49, 21}, {75, 5, 0}};
   test s = new lab2().new test();
   s.Matrix(mas1, mas2);
 }
}
```

Но вас там будет ждать два `exception`. Первый `NullPointerException` так как вы пытаетесь писать какие-то значения в поле `C` класса `lab2`, которое не было инициализировано, а второе `IndexOutOfBound`, который символизирует где-то ошибку в итерации по массиву и выходу за его пределы. Для решения их надо будет самому подебажить ваш метод.